# fetching items from combobox to label text

Tags: c#

I have a combobox say combobox1. I have 4 items in it. Whenever i select an item I wish to get the selected text in the combobox1 on a label text.
I tried doing this using the following code but it does not work.

cnt refers to the number of items in combobox1. lb is an object of label.

Please help..

```
for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
{
    lb.Text = comboBox1.Items[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: `does not work` is never a good explanation, are you getting any error, or your output is not what is expected.

Comment: It also depends on what objects you put in. The object as the item in the listbox should have a `ToString()` method. But you wouldn't see any text in the combobox at all for the items if the underlying object type doesn't implement `ToString()`. But why do you for loop and assign the values (overwriting the previous value) in the label.text? That does not make sense at all.

Comment: @Habib: the output is not what i expect. There is no error. But it does not return anything in label text

Comment: you can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event see my answer, no need to loop. ;)

Comment: @Habib: Yes sir I am using a tostring() method here. But still the result is not as expected.

Comment: `using System.Diagnostics` and use `Debug.Print(comboBox1.Items[i].ToString());` instead of assign it to a label. Then look in your `immediate` window what the output is. You can also use the immediate window while in a breakpoint in scope like this to read what the value of the first item in the combobox is: `?comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();`

Comment: The index of items in a combobox is zero-based. Meaning your for loop should start at 0, your current loop should give you `OutOfRangeException` as `Items.Count` is greater then the last index in the list of items, which is `Items.Count -1`

Comment: I find downvoting an appearently 'newbie' in programming an indication of lacking analytical skills. The questioner doesn't seem to know about events and such, a clear indication of its knowledge of programming, and should therefore be helped to phrase the question properly.... Instead of closing and downvoting. Every experienced C# programmer can make up what the user is `trying` to accomplish (more experiment) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things are wrong with your code:

1. Indices are zero-based (atleast in C# it is). Meaning your for loop should start at `0` and NOT at `1`.
2. You are overwriting the Text value in your label with each iteration in the for loop, that does not make sense. Use `Debug.Print` (`System.Diagnostics` namespace) instead to view all values of the combobox items.
3. You should make use of an event that when a item in the combobox is selected, the value of the label is updated, see this url for a list of events for the combobox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx. Either attach an handler to the event in code or do it in the GUI designer of Visual Studio. Typically you want to use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx
4. Make sure the items in your combobox are of an object type that implements `ToString()`. Otherwise nothing will be shown in your combobox at all.
5. Your current for loop wants to execute `lb.Text = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.Items.Count].ToString();` in the last iteration of the for loop. This will result in a `IndexOutOfRangeException`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb.Text = comboBox1.Text;
        }
```

Comment: No it does not work. it returns system.data...

Comment: `.Text` works, try it :)

Comment: It displays System.Data.Data in the label text

Comment: What's the data in your comboBox? is it not text/ String?

Comment: Sir the data is a text/string like product name, product price.

Comment: It should work, are you still using Loop?

Comment: no, i know .Text is the best way. I have also mentioned it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmbTest.items.count; i++)
{
    label1.text = cmbTest.SelectedItem[i].toString();

}
    //Or
    label1.text = cmbTest.Text;

    //Or
    label1.text = cmbTest.selectedValue;
```

Comment: Re-assigning values to a Text property of a label in a for loop without using the values previously assigned is madness. You could to `label1.text = cmbTest.SelectedItem[cmbTest.items.count-1].toString();` instead, with the same result, and less CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks Mike for valuable info.